# Grails and Spring Security: How catch user into controller?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294015/how-to-get-id-of-the-current-user-logged-in-grails), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526402/how-to-get-current-user-by-using-spring-security-grails-plugin-in-gsp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775053/grails-and-spring-security-how-do-i-get-the-authenticated-user-from-within-a-co) but not resolve my problem.

This is my error:
**Cannot invoke method getCurrentUser() on null object. Stacktrace follows:**
**Message: Cannot invoke method getCurrentUser() on null object**

My code:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured;

@Secured('ROLE_SYSTEMADMIN')
class InstanceController {

...

def save() {
    def instanceInstance = new Instance(params)
def springSecurityService

println("user is"+springSecurityService.getCurrentUser());
...
```

I use:

- GGTS 3.4.0.
- compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'

I'm logged. I'm sure.
Thanks for reply.

Raziel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you defined `springSecurityService` as method variable. You should define it as instance variable:

```
class InstanceController {
  def springSecurityService
  def save() {
    def instanceInstance = new Instance(params)
    println("user is"+springSecurityService.getCurrentUser());
    ..
  }
}
```

Now spring can inject the `springSecurityService` once the controller is created.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is a method injected in every controller: getAuthenticatedUser() that works in the same way. It's also accessible like a controller property: authenticatedUser. It's mentioned [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/single.html#24%20Controller%20MetaClass%20Methods)

Answer (score 0):

The service is not being Injected because you are not stating as a global property of the controller. Declare it out of your save method and then call currentuser property, That should work.