# Grails: How to get username of currently logged in user, and what imports does that require?

Tags: authentication, grails

I simply need the name of the currently logged in user. The same that gets displayed in gsp with `<sec:username/>`. I'm at a loss as to what to do.
Here's previous answers and questions - they all seem to require some import and none of the solutions works for me:

- [Grails Spring Security (get current user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279897/grails-spring-security-get-current-user)
- [How to get id of the current user logged in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294015/how-to-get-id-of-the-current-user-logged-in-grails)
- [How to get current_user by using Spring Security Grails plugin in GSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526402/how-to-get-current-user-by-using-spring-security-grails-plugin-in-gsp)
- [Grails and Spring Security: How do I get the authenticated user from within a controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775053/grails-and-spring-security-how-do-i-get-the-authenticated-user-from-within-a-co)

Specifically, I want to access the username insides a controller and put it into a variable of a domain instance in order to persist it (alongsides other information) into the database for logging purposes. Insides that controller, there's nothing to be seen that even remotely refers to Person/User classes, spring security or any other thing that sounds like it might do what I intend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the domain object corresponding to the logged-in user using `springSecurityService.currentUser`, and then fetch the username (or whichever other properties you require) from there.  Due to Groovy's dynamic nature you don't need to import the domain class or the `SpringSecurityService` class to do this, simply using an untyped dependency injection

```
def springSecurityService
```

and you can access `springSecurityService.currentUser?.username` (or whatever).

Though as Burt points out in a comment, if it's only the username you want then it is more efficient to use `springSecurityService.authentication.principal.username` as this does not need to load the user object from the database.  You only need `currentUser` if you want other properties of the user object aside from the ID or username.

Comment: `currentUser` is an expensive way to get the username since it loads the `User` instance from the db. `authentication.principal.username` is lightweight because it's already cached in-memory

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out: In the controller, `def springSecurityService` comes just after the opening bracket of the controller class (that's `class YourController {`) and the variable assignment looks like this: `def username = springSecurityService.authentication.principal.getUsername()` - apparently playing around with [some code posted here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Getting-logged-in-username-when-using-spring-security-oauth-2-0-1-1-with-grails-2-3-1-td4651324.html) has helped me.

Comment: As that command fails if there's noone logged in, I'm now additionally checking for that beforehand, using: `if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {` - so the code in total is: `String currentUser = ""
            if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
                currentUser = springSecurityService.authentication.principal.getUsername()
            }`

Comment: Quite practical as well - if noone is logged in, `springSecurityService.authentication.getPrincipal()` returns the string `anonymousUser` - [for more details, see the comment on SpringSecurityService.groovy lines 54 to 56, just before `getPrincipal()`](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityService.groovy)